3d to 2d transformation
i have a 3d model with multiple imprint areas on them.

Below is its texture map.
i have the UV map of the bottle aligned with the texture.

but the UV map of imprints is not aligned to the texture of the bottle. it is placed in the center of the texture.

The desired position of imprint is as follows.

Are there any tools/libraries/scripts available to position these UV map pf the imprints with respect to the bottle automatically. Any help/guidance would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

There's a shipped Add-On: 'Export UV Layout'  which will appear in the UV menu when enabled. Does that help?

i have edited the questions. can you please go through them and help me??
